# Help a newbie with a PHP Function

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to use this function:

http://www.frankmacdonald.co.uk/php/post-to-wordpress-with-php.html

Its used to post to Wordpress using XMLRPC, can anyone give me the basics for using this function and maybe a brief over view?

I want to learn how functions work and how to use them.

EDIT:

**The below guideance works like a dream.**

**I want to use a `foreach` loop to cycle through a number of entries and post them all to WP, wonder if anyone could advise?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing much to do here, it's pretty much ready to run already.

Just replace the example values given in the first lines:

```
$title = 'This is the post title'; 
$body = 'this is the post content'; 
$rpcurl = 'http://www.yourwordpressblog.com/xmlrpc.php'; 
$username = 'myusername'; 
$password = 'mypassword'; 
$category = ''; //default is 1, enter a number here. 
$keywords = 'one,two,three';//keywords comma seperated. 
$encoding ='UTF-8';//utf8 recommended
```

with some actual data. (The link to xmlrpc.com should be `www.yourdomain.com/xmlrpc.php` if your blog resides in the root directory.)

Put the whole thing into a PHP file, and run it. If you're lucky, everything will run fine on the first go. If it doesn't, come back and edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to post several items, there are only a few things that change for every post:

- The title of the post.
- The contents of the post
- The category of the post
- The keywords (optional, but I guess you are using it).

The RPC URL, username, password and encoding is standard because I also suppose you're posting it onto the same website. So we only have to store the 4 named items in an array that we can run through. I store the items in another array, so we have an array of arrays.

You could easily write something like this:

```
// We create a post array that contains an array per post.
// I put in the data index based. First item is title, second is content body, third is category, fourth is keywords.
$posts = array(
    array('Title','Contents','category','keywords'),
    array('Another post','More content','another category ID','etc.'),
    // You can add more items if you want.
);

// These are just general settings that are the same for each post.
$rpcurl = 'http://www.yourwordpressblog.com/xmlrpc.php'; 
$username = 'myusername'; 
$password = 'mypassword'; 
$encoding ='UTF-8';

foreach($posts AS $Post)
{
    // From the foreach we get an array with post data each cycle.
    // To keep things a bit clear, I will extract the data to seperate variables..
    $title = $Post[0];
    $body = $Post[1];
    $category = $Post[2];
    $keywords = $Post[3];

    wpPostXMLRPC($title,$body,$rpcurl,$username, $password,$category,$keywords,$encoding); 
}
```

Comment: Yes, on this site certainly. I have hang around on other (dutch) forums as well for a much longer time.